# Google Sheets add a note by appending column based on matching value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, append

The goal is to add a note or several notes over time to a google sheet based on the value chosen.

The script will allow for a button to be added in the sheet and run the script function to append to the next available column.

For example, the name Tim is chosen. A note is written, the button is pressed to run the function and it will add it to Column D (since it is the next available column for Tim).

Another example, the name Jeff is chosen. A note is written. Since there are no more columns the append column should automatically create a new column and allow for the note to be written in "Jeff's" row, which would be Column G

Not sure if this is at all possible but hope to get some suggestions or ideas.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | B+ | completed assignment partly but needed extra time since.. | 89433 | other |  |
| Tim | A | checked |  |  |  |
| Jeff | C | n/a | assignment # 4 | done | other |
| Steve | A | completed | get file | received |  |
| Elon | B- | three out of four | check email |  |  |

Comment: I cannot understand about your current issue and `The goal is to add a note or several notes over time to a google sheet based on the value chosen.`. Especially, I cannot understand about `over time`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you're trying to achieve -

[image: add-note]

And, this code should help you get started -

```
function main() {
  const name = "Steve";
  const note = "HELLO"
  addNote(name, note);
}

function addNote(name, note) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < values.length; rowIndex++) {
    let row = values[rowIndex];
    let nameColumn = row[0];
    if (nameColumn == name) {
      let rowValues = ss.getRange(`${rowIndex+1}:${rowIndex+1}`).getValues()[0]
      .filter(value => value !== "")
      let newColIndex = rowValues.length;
      ss.getRange(rowIndex+1, newColIndex+1).setValue(note);
    }
  }
}
```

Although, I'd highly recommend choosing something else as a unique identifier as opposed to a name because if there are 2 rows with the same name, then the code would actually add notes against both (incorrectly).

Comment: this works perfectly. what if I wanted to add a note from any note that is added in the column to be added to the matching value?

Comment: @Alexander - the part where it says `let rowValues = ss.getRange(`${rowIndex+1}:${rowIndex+1}`).getValues()[0].filter(value => value !== "") ` is already fetching all notes for a specific name.